# LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER not work without location enabled

Tags: android

Android LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER not work without location enabled

I am using

```
locationService.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,this,null)
```

And not getting callback until i enable the location.

I readed in many sources that `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` work without GPS 
Why this happen?

Comment: because that is part of the location permissions, the "sources" you read are wrong

Comment: did you consider the permission bit?

Comment: i checked with fine location and course location permissions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539046/does-locationmanagernetwork-provider-work-without-gps-enabled

Comment: You need to have you location enabled to get any location data PERIOD!!